# Xcode: ScrollView not working

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I somehow can't get a Scrollview to work vertically.
I created a simple ViewController with a Scrollview, that has equal width and height as Safe Area and filled it with one big label, which has also same width as safe area. But it doesn't scroll.
If I don't constrain the label, I get one long line which I can scroll horizontally. Why doesn't it work vertically?

```
<scene sceneID="PWe-2P-e7G">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="dVm-1J-JI9" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="AtX-Pv-6wj">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="768" height="1024"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" ambiguous="YES" showsVerticalScrollIndicator="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="VNx-Wi-Vg6">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="768" height="1024"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" ambiguous="YES" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="MqU-0Y-fM2">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="-117" y="481" width="1000.5" height="61"/>
                                        <mutableString key="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</mutableString>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="40"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="MqU-0Y-fM2" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="VNx-Wi-Vg6" secondAttribute="top" id="rFR-UU-4Jh"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="VNx-Wi-Vg6" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="cuD-5b-v6o" secondAttribute="height" id="5PV-lk-7KG"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="VNx-Wi-Vg6" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="cuD-5b-v6o" secondAttribute="width" id="ZBA-5x-Gzn"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="MqU-0Y-fM2" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="cuD-5b-v6o" secondAttribute="width" id="v3U-b4-7cx"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="cuD-5b-v6o"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="rsr-pH-xUO" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="15.625" y="707.8125"/>
        </scene>
```

Comment: Your label content size needs to be more than the size of the scroll view.

Comment: with that text, text size and constraints it is. At least on my iPad Air

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll view is able to scroll horizontally because the horizontal content size of the label is more than the width of the scroll view horizontally.

I think your code is working perfectly fine.. To see your label working, add lots of new line characters in the label. Something like **i \n am \n and so on**.

After the label has increased its size vertically more than the scroll view size.. it should start scrolling.

Comment: well, withe text and text size above it is larger than the scrollview(as long as I restrict it's width to be equal to safe area), but as I said, it doesn't scroll